# How to avoid Vertical drag selection?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dynamic table here.I completed the drag selection of table cells, but need to prevent the vertical drag selection.How to avoid vertical drag selection?

My [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/9ep1gsr8/1/).

Code:

```
var isMouseDown = false;
$("#mytable td").mousedown(function () {
    isMouseDown = true;
    $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    return false;   // prevent text selection
}).mouseover(function () {
      if (isMouseDown) {
          $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
      }
}).bind("selectstart", function () {
      return false;   // prevent text selection in IE
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, the `bind` is deprecated in newer versions of jQuery, use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

The second, you can save the `parent` in `mousedown` event and check it in `mouseover`. In this way you can check if the `td` is in the same `tr` or not. The updated code might look like this:

```
var isMouseDown = false, parent;

$("#mytable td").mousedown(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    isMouseDown = true;
    parent = $this.closest('tr').get(0);
    $this.toggleClass("highlighted");
    return false;   // prevent text selection
}).mouseover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (isMouseDown && parent === $this.closest('tr').get(0)) {
        $this.toggleClass("highlighted");
    }
}).on("selectstart", function () {
    return false;   // prevent text selection in IE
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ep1gsr8/2/)

**Update:**

I have updated your code. Did some optimizations and added another solution, which adds the `mouseenter` event handler (instead of `mouseover`) only in `mousedown` event handler. Also I have added the code to clear the previous selection.

Here is the final code and corresponding [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ep1gsr8/5/):

```
var isMouseDown = false,
    $cells = $('#mytable td');

$cells.on('mousedown', function() {
    $cells.removeClass('highlighted');    // Clear previous selection
    isMouseDown = true;

    $(this)
        .toggleClass('highlighted')
        .siblings('td')
        .on('mouseenter', onMouseEnter);    // Add mouseenter event handler on siblings

    return false;
}).on('mouseup', function() {
    $(this).siblings('td').off('mouseenter');    // Remove mouseenter event handler from siblings
}).on('selectstart', function() {
    return false;
});

// The onMouseEnter handler
function onMouseEnter() {
    if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    }
}
```